Functional derivative of a function times its derivative
what is the functional derivative of the functional:
$$F\left(\rho(x),\frac{d\rho}{dx}\right)=\rho(x) \frac{d\rho}{dx}\ \ \ \ \ \    (1)$$
with respect to $\rho(x)$?
What changes if we have a function of two variables, i.e. $\rho(x,y)$? In other words, what is the functional derivative with respect to $\rho(x,y)$ of the following expression?
$$F\left(\rho(x,y),\nabla\rho\right)=\rho(x,y) \frac{\partial\rho}{\partial x}\ \ \ \ \ \    (2) $$
I am a bit confused and I cannot work it out from the definitions.
Can you help me please?
Thank you very much for your attention. Best Regards.

It most contexts it would simply be $$\frac{\partial F}{\partial \rho} = \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x}$$ regardless of the changes you suggested.

Is your $F$ defined as $F=\int f$ or $I=\int F$?

"I cannot work it out from the definitions" can you include the definitions you have and perhaps what you have tried?

Thank you very much for all your suggestions

It is derived in Wikipedia that the functional derivative wrt $\rho$ of $I[\rho]=\displaystyle\int F(\mathbf r,\rho(\mathbf r),\nabla\rho(\mathbf r))\,\mathrm d\mathbf r$ for $\mathbf r\in\mathbf R^n$ is
$$\frac{\delta I}{\delta\rho}=\frac{\partial F}{\partial\rho}-\nabla\cdot\frac{\partial F}{\partial \nabla\rho}$$
In your case it should be
$$\frac{\delta I}{\delta\rho(x)}=\frac{\partial F}{\partial\rho}-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial F}{\partial\rho'(x)}=\rho'(x)-\rho'(x)=0$$
for $\rho=\rho(x)$ and
$$\frac{\delta I}{\delta\rho(x,y)}=\frac{\partial F}{\partial\rho}-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial F}{\partial\rho_x(x,y)}-\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\frac{\partial F}{\partial\rho_y(x,y)}=\rho'(x)-\rho'(x)-0=0$$
for $\rho=\rho(x,y)$.

If in reality what you meant by $F$ was
$$F[\rho]=\int f(\mathbf r,\rho(\mathbf r),\nabla\rho(\mathbf r))\, \mathrm d\mathbf x=\rho(\mathbf r)\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x}$$
First you'd need to obtain $f$ using the fundamental theorem of calculus:
$$F=\rho(x)\frac{\mathrm d\rho}{\mathrm dx}=\int\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(\rho(x)\frac{\mathrm d\rho}{\mathrm dx}\right)\,\mathrm dx\iff f=\rho'(x)^2+\rho(x)\rho''(x)$$
Idem with the multivariable case:
$$F=\rho(x,y)\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial x}=\int\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x\partial y}\left(\rho(x,y)\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial x}\right)\,\mathrm d\mathbf x\iff f=\rho_y\rho_{xx}+\rho_{yx}\rho_x+\rho_x\rho_{xy}+\rho\rho_{xyx}$$
And then you'd need to use the functional derivative formula for higher order $\rho$ derivatives (in our case $N=2^{\text{nd}}$ order in $1$ dimension and $N=3^{\text{rd}}$ in $2$ dimensions):
$$\frac{\delta F}{\delta\rho}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial\rho}+\sum_{i=1}^N(-1)^{i}\nabla^{(i)}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \nabla^{(i)}\rho}$$
The definition of $\nabla^{(i)}$ is found on the same section in Wikipedia.

Thank you very much for your suggestion. This clarifies all my doubts in all the possible situations.
